# In React, is it allowed to use props.children elements multiple times?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

For example, if the children is always an `<h3>` at the top:

```
<h3> ... </h3>
<div>other content</div>
```

In the parent component, is it fine to use

```
return (
  { props.children } 
    ... other content
  { props.children[0] } 
);
```

which is to display `props.children[0]` two times, or for whatever reason, to show `props.children` twice.  Is it allowable?  It seems the DOM would point to `props.children[0]` twice, but I checked in the Chrome developer tool that the two DOM elements of `<h3> ... </h3>` are different.

Comment: that would absolutely work. but i'd say assign your props to a constant. like
`const abc = props.children` and then use it as feasible

Answer (score 1):

Sure. **`props` is just an object** so you can use it like normal object (but as you already know, **don't mutate it**.).

Also, even if `props.children[0]` appears twice in `render()`, they will be converted to DOM differently. Because when the JSX converted to Fiber, **each JSX will be converted independently**(and it will be converted to DOM). So the two DOM are different.